# Meaning of these two queries (sql injection)

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Can someone explain why these two queries (sometimes) do cause errors? I googled some explanations but none of them were right. I dont want to fix it. This queries should be actually used for SQL injection attack (I think error based sql injection). Triggered error should be "duplicate entry". I'm trying to found out why are they sometimes counsing errors.

Thanks.

```
select 
    count(*) 
from 
    information_schema.tables 
group by 
    concat(version(),
    floor(rand()*2));

select 
    count(*),
    concat(version(),
    floor(rand()*2))x 
from 
    information_schema.tables 
group by 
    x;
```

Comment: what kind of errors, exactly? And which database product (and version) is this happening on? You mention "sometimes"...so what is the difference in circumstances which cause the errors?

Comment: My question is: WTF is going on with this query to begin with.  It's *grouping* by a random coin-flip?  And getting a *count* of the results of the coinflip?  I'm... really confused as to what the point of the query even is.

Comment: It may be trying to about caching the result. Without context it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the second one is trying to guess which database the victim of the injection is using.

The second one is giving me this:

```
+----------+------------------+
| count(*) | x                |
+----------+------------------+
|       88 | 10.1.38-MariaDB0 |
|       90 | 10.1.38-MariaDB1 |
+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm going to post an answer - and it's more of a frame challenge to the question itself.

**Basically: this query is silly, and it should be written; find out what it's *supposed* to do and rewrite it in a way that makes sense.**

What does the query currently do?

It looks like it's getting a count of the tables in the current database... except it's grouping by a calculated column.  And that column looks like it is Version() and appends either a '0' or a '1' to it (chosen randomly.)

So the end result?  Two rows, each with a numerical value, the sum of which *adds up* to the total number of tables in the current database.  If there are 30 tables, you might get 13/17 one time, 19/11 the next, followed by 16/14.

I have a hard time believing that this is what the query is *supposed* to do.  So instead of just trying to fix the "error" - dig in and figure out what piece of data it *should* be returning - and then rewrite the proc to do it.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for answer. It is designet tu make certain error which can be used for sql injection attack. So I'm not trying to fix it, I'm trying to understad what kind of error might be used for attack (I tryed to use it in database but it wasnt working at all there - maybe because old version of database or something). But thanks again for your time and affort :)

Comment: Uh... what?  I mean, if the attacker is getting to form the SQL statements, querying whatever tables they want under the current access level control... the attack is already succeeding.  Maybe I'm not understanding, but why do you need to generate an error at that point?  About the only possible thing I can imagine is "Privilege Escalation", but I have some doubts that triggering a simple query error is going to get you an elevated permissions level.

Comment: Let me explain, putting on my red-team shirt for a second.  If I find an SQL Injection Vulnerability - say, an address field is being queried as-is without being parameterized (or even sanitized) - I can add my own commands to the search statement being sent to SQL.  So I start adding my own elements to the WHERE clause, systematically grabbing fundamental info about the server instance and its databases.  Once I *find* a vulnerability, I don't *want* to trigger any errors (that might alert you to my presence)  And if you haven't found a vulnerability, you don't have an engine to run your cmd.

Comment: Im just learning so my answer might be bit off  but I think this will be error based SQL injeciton so you want to trigger an error to see data.

Comment: I found out some interesting staff now. I should trigger error similar this one. "Duplicate entry '~'5.1.1-log'~1' for key 1 (this is not exact error just error from similar command. I founded a lot of queries like this which all were designed to make error "duplicate entry" ..